# Furnish Free Template, can't replicate the demo

Tags: templates, shopify, free

Here is the demo: https://furnish-minimal-2.myshopify.com/
and the download link: https://99shopify.com/download/furnish-free-shopify-themes/

I downloaded the naked template and started filling the blanks with my own content. If you go in the demo, placing your mouse over "SHOP" at the top will expand a white window with all the categories. What I can't do is replicate it. I can't seem to figure out how to have BOLD text at the top with non-bold text at the bottom AND also how to make it in 3 different columns.

Here are pictures to help you understand :

**What I'm trying to replicate:** https://imgur.com/89Scn9J

**What mine looks like:**https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUBWT.jpg

**Header using the navigation "main-menu":**https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Hl7.jpg

**What my "main-menu" looks like:**https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVz1f.jpg

Comment: Are you using the 3rd level because, a.k.a the first link is second level menu and the rest are a dropdown to it as a thrid level menu?

Comment: @drip Someone told me that I need the pro version, I bought it and not it is available for me to use it.

What do you mean by 3rd level menu ? could you elaborate please.

Comment: Here is a screen https://imgur.com/a/DigFOJN The 3rd level is the 3 indented item in the menu.